# Can I create a Functor on MyCaseClass[A,B]?

Tags: scala, functor, scalaz

I have already understood how to create a Functor on my own case class when its parameters are of the same type A.

```
case class MyCaseClass[A](a: A, b: A)
val local = MyCaseClass[String]("One", "Two")

implicit val myCaseClassFunctor = new Functor[MyCaseClass]{
  def map[A, B](fa: MyCaseClass[A])(f: A => B) = MyCaseClass(f(fa.a), f(fa.b))
}
val F = Functor[MyCaseClass]

val res = F.map(local)(_ + ".")
println(res)
```

In real life problems, a case class isn't going to be formed by parameters of the same type but different ones.

If the case clase gets to be something as simple as

```
case class MyCaseClass[A, B](a: A, b: B)
```

**Is it possible to build a Functor for it?**

My guess is I can't ever since the definition of map is quite clear with repect to its types parameters

```
def map[A, B]
```

But I have to ask ever since this is my first time programming a Functor.

Answer (score 3):

For a class with two parameters there are two `Functor`s possible: one that maps the first field and another one that maps the second field. While this is the solution, I would recommend to define a `Bifunctor` because it is more general:

```
implicit val bifunctor = new Bifunctor[MyCaseClass] {
  /** `map` over both type parameters. */
  def bimap[A, B, C, D](fab: MyCaseClass[A, B])(f: A => C, g: B => D): MyCaseClass[A, B] =
    MaCaseClass(f(fab.a), g(fab.b))
}
```

Having a `Bifunctor` instance you can easily get a `Functor` for either the left of the right parameter:

```
implicit def functor[X] = bifunctor.leftFunctor[X]
// or
implicit def functor[X] = bifunctor.rightFunctor[X]
```

Answer (score 1):

Functor requires types with a single type parameter, yes, but you can use so-called [type lambdas](http://like-a-boss.net/2014/09/27/type-lambda-in-scala.html):

```
implicit def myCaseClassFunctor[C] = new Functor[({type f[X] = MyCaseClass[C, X]})#f]{
  def map[A,B](fa: MyCaseClass[C,A])(f:A=>B) = MyCaseClass(fa.a, f(fa.b))
}
```